# Collect values together in subdicts by the first value in a tuple key

Tags: python, dictionary

hi i have something like

```
pq={<Timestamp: 2008-02-02 13:30:46>: {('1059', 'latitude'): 40.064889999999998,
                                ('1059', 'longitude'): 116.56359,
                                ('1466', 'latitude'): 39.92163,
                                ('1466', 'longitude'): 116.32633,
                                ('1563', 'latitude'): 39.864249999999998,
                                ('1563', 'longitude'): 116.39328,
                                ('1827', 'latitude'): 40.003770000000003,
                                ('1827', 'longitude'): 116.30907000000001}}
```

and i want something like

```
pq={<Timestamp: 2008-02-02 13:30:46>: {'1059':{'latitude: 40.064889999999998,'longitude': 116.56359},
                                       '1466' :{'latitude': 39.92163,'longitude': 116.32633},
                                       '1563':{'latitude': 39.864249999999998, 'longitude':116.39328},
                                       '1827':{'latitude': 40.003770000000003,'longitude': 116.30907000000001}}
```

How do i do that?

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty trivial. You go through the original dictionary, extract the data you want and build a new dictionary. It's hard to be more specific without actually writing the code for you, and I don't think you will learn as much if I do that.

Comment: also, <Timestamp: 2008-02-02 13:30:46> is not a valid dict key.

Comment: @dansalmo I'm sure that's what you get if you print `pq` -- the key is a `Timestamp` class that prints itself like that.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro, i had tried extracting the first columns in the tuple and possibly searching back into the dictionary pq and build a new dictionary. but for that i was trying something like this.
print set(np.asarray(pq[x].keys())[:,0])
This seems to add a lot of overhead. converting from tuple to a numpy array and then a set.

Comment: @dansalmo, Timestamp is a valid dict key. Timestamp is used extensively in pandas (tool for spatial data analysis in python)

Comment: @user2179627: My point is that when asking questions here, you should include what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make subdicts by splitting up the tuple keys.

In order to automatically create the subdicts, use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Iterating over the items of the dictionary you want to modify allows you to use tuple unpacking to split up the tuple keys:

```
>>> import collections
>>> subpq = collections.defaultdict(dict)
>>> for (number, type), value in pq.values()[0].items():
...  subpq[number][type] = value
... 
>>> subpq
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>,
            {'1059': {'latitude': 40.06489, 'longitude': 116.56359},
             '1827': {'latitude': 40.00377, 'longitude': 116.30907},
             '1563': {'latitude': 39.86425, 'longitude': 116.39328},
             '1466': {'latitude': 39.92163, 'longitude': 116.32633}})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you gave me the lead.
I could follow what you said i write something like this.


    x=df.index[0] #first index of a dataframe which is a timestamp
    subpq[x]={}<br/>
    for (number,type),value in pq.values()[0].items():<br/>
    if number not in subpq[x].keys():<br/>
        subpq[x].update({number:{type:value}})<br/>
    else:<br/>
        subpq[x][number].update({type:value})<br/>